# Installing libssl-dev package in ubuntu using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to install the libssl-dev package in ubuntu using ansible.
I have this task:

```
- name: Install libssl-dev package
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    pkg: libssl-dev
    state: build-dep
  become: true
```

But I am getting this error:

> STDERR: E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list MSG:
> '/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o
> "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold"      build-dep 'libssl-dev'' failed:
> E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list

How can I fix this?

Comment: In order to install `build-dep` packages, you need `/etc/apt/sources.list` to contains `deb-src` repositories, per default, on Ubuntu, those lines are commented. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list. This is not a programming question though, but a system admin / configuration one, so it is not suited for this Q&A.

Comment: I got you, Thanks

Comment: I have uncommented all lines from sources.list but I am still getting this error: E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list

Comment: I added sudo apt update and it worked